# Flutter fails to build android-arm64, android-x64 release versions

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, release

I tried building my flutter app as an Android App Bundle, but the build fails for

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm64
```

and

```
 flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-x64
```

with exception an exception (same for both commands)

```
c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\compiler\backend\il.h: 999: error: unreachable code
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073740791
Target android_aot_release_android-x64 failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073740791
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        31,1s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

However, building for android-arm works just fine:

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm
```

Running `flutter doctor -v` works just fine.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at D:\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (4 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\Android_Development_Requirements\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
```

I really can't figure out why, does anybody know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is your cd <app dir> is in the correct location? It should have the current location of the project.

Comment: Try `flutter upgrade` then build you app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was related to the `moor_ffi` library, though I couldn't figure out why exactly, however switching to `moor_flutter` fixed it.